# MERN: Refresh loads raw data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

Why does my deployed MERN app return raw data on page refresh?

When a specific `get` request is called, raw data from mongo displays on the screen like [this](https://snipboard.io/4OSXVL.jpg). I just deployed to Heroku and this issue does not happen on my local server. My thinking is that the issue could be with `Editor.js`, however, a boolean state change is used to delay render until all data is loaded.

The data returned is correct, so the Axios call is successful. It's just weird that the React component isn't being rendered.

On refresh, this is called:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    initialDataLoadEditor();
  }, []);

  async function initialDataLoadEditor() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/document/${id}`);

      setData(response.data);
      setIsLoaded(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

if (isLoaded === false) {
    return <div>LOADING...</div>;
  } return (
      <div>

        <div className='flex justify-center'>
          <label >
            <TextareaAutosize
              className={`  mt-2 mb-2  flex-child outline-none resize-none text-2xl font-bold`}
              type="text"
              ref={nameRef}
              defaultValue={data.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleSave(e)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <EditorJs
          instanceRef={(instance) => (instanceRef.current = instance)}
          placeholder="Start typing what's in your head..."
          tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}
          enableReInitialize={true}
          data={data.components[0]}
          onChange={(e) => handleSave(e)}
        />
      </div>
    );
```

Been working on this since the AM and I'm really not sure what's going on. Any idea how to render the React component? Thank you!

Comment: I believe that something is wrong with heroku settings. I bet that it works as expected on you local machine

Comment: @Sonny49 Thank you for the reply! You are correct, it works without a problem on my local machine. Is this something I should contact heroku about?

Comment: You are using a `/document/[id]` URL for both the frontend and backend. Navigating there using react-router works because the URL change is "fake", but now refreshing the page will make the browser request the actual URL from the server, and the backend replies with the document data in JSON form as it's supposed to. To make refreshing work with react-router, your server needs to send the main index for all app routes. Not sure how this works on the local server but either a) figure out how and implement the same mechanism on heroku or b) add `/api/` or something to the start of your data URLs

Comment: @ChrisG That fixed it! Thank you so much for the help! Not sure how to close out this ticket but if you post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the solution for people in the future :)

Comment: Changing the URL will fix this however since your previous solution did work on localhost and I don't know how to do the same on heroku I didn't post an answer. I once had the browser redirect all my URL requests to the main index (breaking my app); turned out this was thanks to a service worker that came with `create-react-app` and has since been changed. Maybe a service worker is what's enabling this for localhost but didn't make it to heroku?

Comment: @ChrisG I think what could be happening is that on localhost, it's running on 2 ports. So serverside we're on localhost:5000/document/:id and then on client side we're hitting localhost:4000/document/:id. I'm assuming since those are technically 2 different paths, it's working without any issues.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely explain it :)